# Programmatic download of a file on Web server

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am having some files on IIS web Server which I want to download using javascript/JSP or batch script.For example I am having a file with url http://10.1.25.147/repapp/20101229/bal.txt .
When I open the file in browser it ask me interactively to save the file.What I want is that it should download this file to client pc  using some script.

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify you want to automatically download a file to a client pc when they visit a website without user interaction? There are whole papers and seminars that occur to prevent such things from happening. I realize that doesn't help you. Maybe you can explain the motive for what you need and we might find a acceptable solution.

Comment: Please clarify for us... you're trying to force a user to download a file without their permission from a web page? (Not possible, and for good reason!)  Or, you're writing javascript running on the host PC using the windows scripting host or something and you want to download a file?

Comment: Don't you think it will break security ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking if you can *force* a file to be downloaded to a client's computer without asking permission from the client, then I'm going to say that this isn't doable (and hope that nobody proves me wrong).

The best you can do is provide the browser with the proper headers on the download to suggest what it should do (the type of the response, a suggested name of the file, etc.).  However, it's up to the settings in the user's browser as to what it will automatically do with that information and whether or not it will permit the download.

Comment: Hi,I will tell you my motive.I want to download the files from the server programata=ically and then ftp these file to a different host for further processing.I want to do it programatically because the end user does not want to download files individually and then upload it to ftp server.

Comment: @Manohar: Why not FTP the files from the server to the FTP location?  Why involve the client at all?  Or does the client need to do something manually before FTPing the files?